# Delayed scroll floating element effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Using CSS & JS, I'm trying to create an element with position `fixed` but with a slightly delayed scroll like a spring.

Some examples I've found so far:

1. http://www.echoecho.com/toolfloatinglayer.htm
2. http://yaireo.github.io/stickyfloat/

The issue with these examples is that the effect is jittery and not smooth.

Is there a smooth & modern solution available?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help

Comment: I don't really have any code yet, just an element with `position: fixed`